# Multi Threading iOS, Fast launch UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, multithreading

In my ios app i have included google,facebook and twitter integrations. When application starts it loads thus APIs before loading UI.

How to multithread as my UI Loads first making a fast launch. My didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // Add code here to do background processing
        //
        //

        NSLog(@"Thread Excecution started");

        NSError* configureError;
        [[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError: &configureError];
        NSAssert(!configureError, @"Error configuring Google services: %@", configureError);

        [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;


        [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Add code here to update the UI/send notifications based on the
            // results of the background processing

            NSLog(@"Thread Excecution completed");
        });
    });
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: You know there's no guarantee when a notification might actually fire and be received even on the main thread right? Are you sure you wanna do that?

Comment: And why do you need to write the external API's launch code in background thread anyways?

Comment: Can i add these code in Viewdidload instead? is that will work

Comment: you can use `NSOperationQueue` to mannually handle each thread if needs.

Comment: Again, What exactly is your problem with doing it in AppDidLaunch? And no if the Framework says initiate it in AppDelegate then that's what you have to do. Right now it is super unclear what exactly  is your problem and what do you seek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using multiple thread, then you can use dispatch_group concept.

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

//block 1
dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
   // code here
});
//block 2
dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
   // code here
});

//block 3
dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
   // block 3 will get notify, after block 1 and block 2 complete their tasks.
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [animationImageView stopAnimating];

        [self createUI];
    });
}
```

Here block block 1 and block 2 will run paralelly and after they complete their work, block 3 will get notify.